# WAMP Not Starting

Tags: mysql, xampp, wamp

I'm trying to get started with WAMP server on a Windows 10 computer. When I try to launch the WAMP application on the computer, I get an error message that says **This application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).**

The WAMP icon in the taskbar tray is orange, with 2 of 3 services running.

I am still able to access the WAMP dashboard through **localhost** in my browser.

I've gone through and installed all the required Visual C++ redistributables to no avail.

I've enabled both the .NET frameworks.

I've installed Microsoft DirectX.

I've restarted the computer.

I don't have Skype.

Running as an administrator.

*Some of the things I tried might be completely useless, I was just watching a few YouTube videos about how to resolve this error.*

**It says in 'services.msc' that it's mySQL that isn't running. Only MariaDB and Apache appear in services.msc, but I'm still able to access phpMyAdmin**

Does anyone know what could be the issue? I'm just about at the stage of uninstalling WAMP and starting again, or maybe trying XAMPP instead.

**UPDATE**: I reinstalled WAMP entirely, and now I have a green icon in the taskbar, with all services running, however I am still not able to open the WAMP application as per the above question. Can I use WAMP without using the desktop client?

Comment: Did you read the initial dialog in the install and install all the MSVC RUntimes **both 32bit and 64bit** BEFORE installing WAMPServer? The WAMPManager is still a 32 bit app and therefore requires the 32bit MSVC runtimes

Comment: Yeah I uninstalled it, then made sure everything was installed, then redownloaded it. Everything works now, I just can't access the Windows client or the taskbar icon.

Comment: Go to the [WAMPServer alternate Repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and at the bottom of the page you will find a link to download `All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)` Its a zip, unzip it and then install all the MSVC RUntimes in a logical order oldest version first. If the library is already installed it will offer a REPAIR option, click that. This will make sure you have ALL the possible required runtimes.

Comment: Just above that, there is this link `Checks VC++ packages installed` download an run that, it will let you know which libraries are actually missing from your system